# How can I use scala with jupyter notebook?

Tags: scala, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I want to use scala with jupyter notebook, the same way we use IJulia.

One solution that I found was by cloning https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala

Is there any other way out ?

Comment: [Apache Toree](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree) also provides a scala kernel for Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jupyter documentation](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/subprojects.html?highlight=jupyterhub#kernels) links to [IPython kernels for other languages](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages)

It appears to be a comprehensive list.